# Linux user space threads, kernel threads , lightweight processes

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

I am bit confused with all this enteties and how they interconnected in Linux. "Unix internals" book states that `lightweight process (LWP)` is kernel-supported user thread, and that kernel doesn't see threads inside processes. Is it stil true for Linux?

As I understand, user-space threads scheduled inside process, by higher level abstraction as `pthread` library, without kernel's intervention. Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In pthreads on Linux, the thread scheduling is handled by the kernel.

In Linux, a thread or process is created with the `clone()` system call (`fork()` is a special case of clone). Depending on the options passed to clone, the newly created process will be lighter weight or a heavier weight (i.e. having a separate memory space and a separate set of file descriptors etc.). `pthread_create()` uses `clone()` with a minimum amount of separation.

It is also possible to not make use of native threads at all, and instead use a fully userspace implementation of threading, using `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`. This could be used to implement some interpreted language, for example. However, I am not aware of a concrete example of a program or library that actually does implement its own userspace scheduler.

One more thing: a "*kernel thread*" is generally used to designate a thread that runs in kernel space, i.e. that is part of the kernel itself. In `ps` such threads are recognisable because they are surrounded with square brackets, like `[kthreadd]`.

Comment: LinuxThreads implementation still uses 1:1 user thread to kernel schedulable thread mapping (only it maps to processes, and NPTL - glibc's posix threads maps to kernel schedulable threads). There was only NGPT (Next Generation POSIX Threads) to 2003 with probably non 1:1 mapping; and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads are sometimes implemented in language interpreters.

Comment: @osgx OK, thanks for the explanation. I removed the reference to LinuxThreads to avoid confusion.

Comment: The Go language (golang) is an example of an implementation of N:M green threads (goroutines) running on top of real threads.

Comment: Oh heh, see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/222694/5044

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, for threads implemented in user-space, the kernel isn't aware of threads. 
So if one thread blocks, the other threads belonging to the same process block as well, as the OS isn't aware of threading.

Comment: The information given in this answer if mostly incorrect. The first paragraph is correct because it speaks of threads implemented in user-space. But then you continue talking about LightWeightProcesses in general, and these are usually normal processes, not threads implemented in userspace. Also, a kernel thread is a thread that fully runs in kernel space and has no userspace counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

> a LWP(lightweight processes) runs in user space on top of a single kernel thread and shares
>   its address space and system resources with other LWPs within the same
>   process.

FROM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_process

In linux, lwp is on top of kernel thread, and share resources. some language like golang(coroutine) 
 have user thread by himself scheduler.