# what is the difference between application threads and OS threads?

Tags: multithreading, java-threads

from http://coding-geek.com/how-databases-work/#Global_overview

*The process manager: Many databases have a pool of processes/threads that needs to be managed. Moreover, in order to gain nanoseconds, some modern databases use their own threads instead of the Operating System threads.*

what is the difference between application threads and os threads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux user space threads, kernel threads , lightweight processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818104/linux-user-space-threads-kernel-threads-lightweight-processes)

Comment: Biggest difference might be that an application can not schedule its different "application threads" (a.k.a., "green threads") to run on different processors.  There's no way to do that without making the kernel aware of the threads, and if the kernel is aware of them, then by definition, they would be kernel threads.

Answer (score 1):

"Application threads" is another form of [M:N thread model, or hybrid threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#M:N_.28hybrid_threading.29).

> M:N maps some M number of application threads onto some N number of
>   kernel entities,[10] or "virtual processors." This is a compromise
>   between kernel-level ("1:1") and user-level ("N:1") threading. In
>   general, "M:N" threading systems are more complex to implement than
>   either kernel or user threads, because changes to both kernel and
>   user-space code are required. In the M:N implementation, the threading
>   library is responsible for scheduling user threads on the available
>   schedulable entities; this makes context switching of threads very
>   fast, as it avoids system calls. **However, this increases complexity
>   and the likelihood of priority inversion, as well as suboptimal
>   scheduling without extensive (and expensive) coordination between the
>   userland scheduler and the kernel scheduler.**

There always seems to be attempts to use "application threads" to improve performance.

Java did it - "green threads".  And dropped it around Java 1.2.

Solaris used to have an M:N threading model, and dropped it starting in Solaris 8.

AFAIK, Windows and Linux never went there.

Now, [Rust seems to want to try their hand at it](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-November/006550.html).